# safest way to redo aliases

Tags: path-aliases

So a site in production wants certain aliases to be redone. If there's another way to do this other than `Home » Administration » Configuration » Search and metadata » URL aliases > Delete aliases`, please let me know. I dont want to run that if it's going to break the site since it is in production. I can always rebuild using `Bulk Update > Content Paths` after `Delete aliases` . Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Don't have a solution, but some thoughts: Deleting the aliases is probably the worst way to do this as it won't create redirects from the old aliases. You want a method that creates 301 redirects from old aliases to the new. Otherwise you'll have a bunch of dead links and bookmarks, lose google rankings etc. But I recommend to not do anything on a production site without testing it offline first!

Comment: This is an internal site so google rankings isnt important. But youre right in regards to dead links and bookmarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find "Update URL alias" as one of the choices for bulk operations for nodes under admin/content

[image]

This way you can select which specific nodes that needs URL aliases rebuilt instead of deleting and rebuilding all.

Comment: Hi, I dont see that though in my options.. How do I add that option there?

Comment: Maybe you have overriden the default administer content view?

Comment: Youre right. I didnt create the site from the beginning so I had no clue until now... Do you know how I can add this back or another way to do it ?

Comment: The content overview page could be overriden in different ways. Another way to add your own view that has bulk operations available is by installing Views Bulk operations https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations